# md-sidenav toggle right and changed the width of the html page I am getting some delay when the close button is clicked

Tags: angular-material

When I am using md-sidenav toggle right and changed the width of the html page I am getting some delay when the close button is clicked.Please see the below link. Also how to adjust the sidenav css so that it takes different width based on parent container width-responsive.
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VaGxrN

```
  <md-content flex="" layout-padding="">

  <div layout="column" layout-fill="" layout-align="top center">
    <p>
    The left sidenav will 'lock open' on a medium (>=960px wide) device.
    </p>
    <p>
    The right sidenav will focus on a specific child element.
    </p>

    <div>
      <md-button ng-click="toggleLeft()" class="md-primary" hide-gt-md="">
        Toggle left
      </md-button>
    </div>

    <div>
      <md-button ng-click="toggleRight()" ng-hide="isOpenRight()" class="md-primary">
        Toggle right
      </md-button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div flex=""></div>

</md-content>

<md-sidenav class="md-sidenav-right md-whiteframe-4dp" md-component-id="right">

  <md-toolbar class="md-theme-light">
    <h1 class="md-toolbar-tools">Sidenav Right</h1>
  </md-toolbar>
  <md-content ng-controller="RightCtrl" layout-padding="">
    <form>
      <md-input-container>
        <label for="testInput">Test input</label>
        <input type="text" id="testInput" ng-model="data" md-autofocus="">
      </md-input-container>
    </form>
    <md-button ng-click="close()" class="md-primary">
      Close Sidenav Right
    </md-button>
  </md-content>

</md-sidenav>
```